# integration $\int \frac{-4x+5}{\sqrt{12x-4x^2-8}}$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{-4x+5}{\sqrt{12x-4x^2-8}}$$

**My attempt:**

$-4x^2+12x-8=-(2x-3)^2+1$

$$\begin{align}\int \frac{-4x+5}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}}\,dx&=\int \frac{-4x}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}}\,dx+\int \frac{5}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}}\,dx\\
&=
-4\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}}\,dx+5\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}}\,dx\\
&=-4\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}}\,dx+5\arcsin(2x-3)
\end{align}$$

$$-4\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}}\,dx$$

$u=2x-3 \rightarrow du=2dx$

$x=\frac{u+3}{2}$

$$-4\cdot\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\frac{u+3}{2}}{\sqrt{1-(u)^2}}du=-\int \frac{u+3}{\sqrt{1-(u)^2}}du$$
$s=u^2$

$ds=2udu$

$$-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-s}}ds+\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-s}}ds=-\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}+5\arcsin(2x-3)-3\arcsin(2x-3)+c=-\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}+2\arcsin(2x-3)+c$$

But it is wrong according to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive%20-sqrt%281-%282x-3%29%5E2%29%29%2B2arcsin%282x-3%29)

Comment: Is this your attempt?

Comment: @Nehorai yes it is mine

Comment: Aren't you missing out a factor 2 in the first arc sine integral?

Comment: @Justpassingby why? it is $(5arcsin(x))'=\frac{5}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Comment: I would have written $-4x+5=-2(2x-3)-1$. That will make your integrals much easier.

Comment: So what is the derivative of $5\arcsin(2x-3)$ @gbox?

Comment: @gbox : You have to write "dx".

Comment: if I derive my result and get $\frac{4x-7}{\sqrt{12x-4x^2-8}}$ is it only a change in a constant so it is ok?

Comment: No, it is not a change of a constant. The derivative should be exactly equal - it cannot differ by a constant. (But here, it does not differ by a constant, it differs by a some $\frac{C}{\sqrt{12x-4x^2-8}}$.) The *integral* can differ by a constant. @gbox

Comment: Basically, this is much easier if you immediately let $u=2x-3$ and $du=2\,dx$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews unlike your answer?

Comment: Well, my answer could easily be modified that way - I essentially am doing that. You first set $v=2x-3$, and then $u=1-u^2$ for the first part. But I decided to go with a slight variant, to keep the answer brief. @gbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that $-4x+5=-2(2x-3)-1$, you get:

$$\int \frac {-2(2x-3)}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}}\,dx -\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}}\,dx$$
In the first, let $u=1-(2x-3)^2$, then $du=-4(2x-3)\,dx$ and in the second, let $v=2x-3$ and you get the integrals:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}} - \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$

This gives you $\sqrt{u} + \frac{1}{2}\arcsin(v)=\sqrt{12x-4x^2-8} - \frac{1}{2}\arcsin(2x-3)$.